# Can I change the image associated with my computer when it's sharing as a media server?

Tags: icons, file-sharing, media-server

I currently have my computer setup to share its videos, music, and pictures as a media server so I can easily access all of my stuff from my PS3 and play it on my TV (since I can't connect my computer directly to my TV). However, my dad also has his laptop setup as a media server, for whatever reason, and both of them use the same "Windows Media Player" icon in the list. It's not a *huge* issue, but I was wondering if it was possible to somehow change what icon gets sent out by your computer to other devices when it's acting as a media server, and how?

[image: The icons in question]

Answer (score -1):

THIS ANSWER IS NOT FOR "WINDOWS MEDIA PLAYER". Because it is Impossible to do it there Or you should change your platform (ie install Linux etc.).
You could use PS3 Media Server. I found some information on http://www.ps3mediaserver.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=11489
I paste the exact text:

> **REQUIREMENTS:**
>     - You need to have following: Windows, WinRar, PMS
>     - You must validate the paths of PMS.exe and WinRar.exe in "Settings.conf"
>     - PMS cannot be running while changing name/icon
>
> **HOW TO INSTALL AND USE:**
>     - Download the files: https://sites.google.com/site/moviemetacreator/tools/PMSNAICv0.6.rar
>     - Extract the files to a folder anywhere local on your computer.
>     - Remember to check the paths are correct in "Settings.conf"
>     - That's it.. from there use the two bat files, SetName.bat and SetIcon.bat
>
> **How to use SetName.bat :**
>     You simply double click the file, and it will prompt you for a name.
>     **Alternatively you can call this bat from commandline/script with the png file as argument*
>
> **How to use SetIcon.bat :**
>     Simply drag drop a png file onto the bat file, and it will do the rest
>     **Alternatively you can call this bat from commandline/script with the png file as
>   argument*
>
> *Note: The PNG should have a size of 256x256 pixel (24bit)*

Comment: I wouldn't personally trust those files

Comment: It is `sites.google.com` ! Not `pieceOfCrap.sth`. I wrote the better option as what he wants is IMPOSSIBLE!